# C++/CLI Assembly for .NET application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, .net-assembly

I'm currently working on a .NET assembly for an existing application. This application calls a specific function in a file which should be called external.dll. I have some C#-code, which after compiling is working properly with the application:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

/// Sample external.dll code
namespace External
{
    public class Handler
    {
        public void Execute(int row, double duration, string comment,     double[] argument)
        {
            //Some code
        }
    }
}
```

Scince I have written a large program in C++, which should be called by the application I'd like to write the external.dll in c++.
I tried to rewrite the C#-code in C++ using the Visual studio C++/CLR Class Library template but during the startup of the existing application there is an error saying: "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded".

Since I'm new to the .NET framework programming I'm a bit confused. I thought that using the C++/CLR template should generate the same CIL code as using C#.

Comment: Check the project settings of your C++/CLI project and review the targeted runtime. Set it to match the one of your C# project.

Comment: C++/CLI is only one of options. CppSharp is another commonly used option, https://github.com/mono/CppSharp

Comment: I've used the same target runtime version for the c++ code as well as the c# code. I also tried it with every runtime version currently installed on my machine. The error is still there

Comment: There is no decent way to force a C++ program to use an older version of the framework.  Any C++/CLI program built with VS2010 and up must always target .NET 4.x.  Not arbitrary, you link a runtime library that contains .NET code to provide the glue.  Your C# project must comply and not target anything older than 4.0 either.  So simply use Project > Properties > Application tab and upgrade the "Target framework" setting.  Still using 3.5 or less stopped making sense a long time ago.  If that is a show-stopper then you need to build your C++/CLI project with VS2008.